# for-each loop index

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, foreach, indexing

I have this piece of code:

```
int[] tab2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7, 8, 9, 0};
for(int i : tab2)
    System.out.print(i + " ");

int[] tab3 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7, 8, 9, 0};
for(int i : tab3)
    System.out.print(tab3[i] + " ");
```

The first loop gives me 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0

while the second one gives me 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1

how come? Isn't the first index of an array 0?

Comment: The for-loop iterates over array **values**, not **indices** *(or is that indexes?)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second loop you are printing value by looking from tab3's items.

```
tab3[tab3[0]], tab3[tab3[1]], tab3[tab3[2]], ...
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first iteration of the second loop, `i` equals to `1` .. and hence `tab3[i]` is `2`.

Answer (score 0):

In each case, the for loop causes `i` to take on each of the values in the array.  The first loops prints each of those values, as you'd expect.

But in the second loop, the values are used as the indices into the `tab3[]` array.

As `i` takes on the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0,
the printed values are `tab3[1]`, `tab3[2]`, ..., `tab3[0]`,
which, as you wrote, are 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1.

You'll get the values you expected if you loop `i` through the values from 0 to 9, like this:

```
for (i = 0;  i < 10;  ++i) 
  System.out.print(tab3[i] + " ");
```